# Redux Saga's race won't trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, redux-saga

I tried to make a 'simple' saga where I race a `'chain' of sagas` and a `CANCEL` action. The race is going down smoothly, and the `task` is 'winning', BUT the race will return an `empty object` (so my `if(task)` won't get called, even though the race went down properly).

How it's works:
task: 
I call the `allActivity` function.
allActivity calls the `uploadData` function with an array of objects.
After that I basically just upload each item one by one with the sage.

Code:

```
function* handleSingle(item) {
    const respone = yield call(myFetch, item)
    return response
}

function* uploadData(data) {
    yield all(data.map(item=>handleSingle(item)))
}

function* allActivity() {
    const data = yield select(state=>state.data)
    yield call(uploadData, data)
}

function* uploadJobWorker() {
    const { task, cancel } =  yield race({
        task: call(allAcivity),
        cancel: take(ON_CANCEL)
    })

    if(task)
        console.warn('done')
    if(cancel)
        console.warn('cancelled')

    console.warn('end')
}
```

So after the race is finished I can see the 'end' logged out, but not the 'done'. And if the cancel get triggered I can see the 'cancelled' logged out. (so the only part what never get triggered is the 'done')

Comment: `call` doesn't return a task but instead returns the return value of a function/generator. Return value of `allActivity` is undefined and so the `task` variable is resolved to undefined as well.

Comment: Ohh this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by a quite simple way.

```
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

function* handleSingle(number) {
    const response = yield call(delay, 1000)
    console.warn(`${number} is finished`)
    return response
}

const mock = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

function* uploadData() {
    for(const number of mock) {
        yield call(handleSingle, number)
    }
    yield put({ type: FINISHED })
}

function* allActivity() {
    yield call(uploadData)
}

function* uploadJobWorker() {
    yield fork(allActivity)
    const { task, cancel, error } =  yield race({
        task: take(FINISHED),
        cancel: take(CANCEL),
        error: take(ERROR),
    })

    if(task)
        console.warn('done')
    if(cancel)
        console.warn('cancel')
    if(error)
        console.warn('error')

    console.warn('end')
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        takeEvery(EXAMPLE, uploadJobWorker)
    ])
}
```

So instead of calling it. I will fork it so it's won't block the saga. And instead waiting for a FINISHED action.